# How to read control / variable value in rdlc?

Tags: expression, rdlc

I want to display the value from dropdown on aspx page to the rdlc header.
how can i achieve this.

Comment: have you got it working?

Answer (score 2):

Create a text parameter for your report to accept the value, then add a label to your report header and enter an expression such as `=Parameters!TheDropDownText.Value` for its value; you'll need to supply the report parameter its value when you run the report, but that's another topic :)